# Why did not I get segmentation fault?

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64

I'm new to assembly programming and experementing with simple examples and gdb. Here is the program I wrote:

1.asm

```
section .text
    global _start
    extern _print_func

_start:
    push str
    movzx rdx, byte [str_len]
    push dx ;  <---  typo here, should be rdx
    call _print_func

    mov rax, 60
    syscall

section .data
    str: db 'Some data',0x0A,0x0D
    str_len: db $ - str
```

2.asm

```
section .text
    global _print_func

_print_func:
    pop rbx
    pop rdx
    pop rsi
    mov rax, 0x01
    mov rdi, 0x01
    syscall
    push rbx
    ret

section .data
    str: db 'Some string',0x0A,0x0D
    str_len: db $ - str
```

After compiling, linking (with `ld`) and running the program it just printed nothing. So I examined the content of registers before the `syscall` made.

```
(gdb) info registers 
rax            0x1      1
rbx            0x4000c5 4194501
rcx            0x0      0
rdx            0x6000e4000b     412331802635  ; <-- obviously wrong
rsi            0x10000  65536
rdi            0x1      1
rbp            0x0      0x0
rsp            0x7fffffffdcc6   0x7fffffffdcc6
```

So the syscall should try read `412331802635` bytes starting at `0x10000` which I thought should have caused Segmentation Fault since the program is not allowed to access all the bytes.

But it silently printed nothing. Why? Why didn't Segmantation Fault raised? Was that some sort of undefined behavior? I'n using `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` under `intel core i5`.

Comment: `read` doesn't cause a segfault, it returns an error.

Comment: Run your program under `strace` to decode the args and return values of system calls.  See also the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more asm debugging tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sys_write` does not raise a segfault, it just returns an `-EFAULT` error code. You should see that in `rax` after the `syscall` finishes. See also [man 2 write](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)

Comment: Just tried it and got `rax            0xfffffffffffffff2       -14`. Now understood, thanks much.